# Can't connect using Jail SFTP account

Tags: ubuntu, security, ssh, sftp

I've been following this tutorial "[Limiting Access with SFTP Jails on Debian and Ubuntu](http://library.linode.com/security/sftp-jails/)" and whilst I've had no errors setting it up, I've had issues on Ubuntu 10.04LTS logging in as a user on a virtualhost. I've changed my SSH port to 22022, and enter all the credentials when attempting to login.

I ran these commands to add a user to the virtualhost:

```
# useradd -d /srv/www/[domain] [username]
# passwd [username]
# usermod -G filetransfer [username]
# chown [username]:[username] /srv/www/[domain]/public_html
```

I should add that this is the only time I've setup the user they have no other /home directories or such. The directory that does exist is at /srv/www/example.com/public_html

When I try using a desktop package such as cyberduck to login to the site, I keep getting a "Login failed with this username or password". I am completely lost as what to do next...

The reason why I'm trying this method is because I want my clients to use SFTP and not FTP to upload files to their websites. Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the logs on your system?  For example, /var/log/auth.log might provide some information as to why the authentication is denied.  Alternatively, /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages might have information relating to a configuration error on the SFTP subsystem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I managed to find out the issue: "User sftpuser from 12.34.56.78 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers". Seems as though I should add the "filetransfer" usergroup to the Allowed users list - maybe you could give some direction on how to do that?

Comment: I actually have "Match group filetransfer ChrootDirectory %h..." listed in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. I wonder why the group isn't getting any special treatment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Install MySecureShell http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysecureshell/
- Create users with:

  useradd -d /srv/www/[domain] -s /bin/MySecureShell [username]

  Here it goes the passwd, mkdir and chown
- Check MySecureShell at /etc/ssh/sftp_config, be sure you have this line

  Home    $HOME
- Check the other configurations like download/upload bandwidth limit or connections limits.
- Be sure you can access the public_html directory by apache user or whatever user runs apache server. Maybe you can do:

  chown -R [username]:apache /srv/www/[domain]